# How to create a livestream from a capture of a canvas element using websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, html5-canvas, webm

Im trying to send the [canvas.captureStream()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) to an http listener to create a livestream. My problem is I don't know how to parse MediaStream object to be a valid image or webm video. Here is my code.

Server

```
var http = require('http')
var Server = require('ws').Server
var port = 9001
var videoPort = 9000
var ws = new Server({port: port})

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.connection.setTimeout(0)
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": "video/webm", //not really sure about the format
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes"
  })
  ws.on('connection', function(w){
    console.log('connected')
    w.on('message', function(mediaStreamObjectFromClient){
      // mediaStreamObjectFromClient
      // parse here the data sent from the canvas capture.
    })

    w.on('close', function() {
      console.log('closing connection')
    })
  })

}).listen(videoPort, '127.0.0.1')

console.log(`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:${videoPort}`)
```

Client

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9001');
var timer = 0
var can = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = can.getContext('2d')

connection.onopen = function () {
  var intervalID = window.setInterval(() =>{
    draw()
    timer++
  }, 1000)
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
  ctx.font = "75px serif";
  ctx.strokeText(timer, 10, 50)
  connection.send(can.captureStream(25),{binary:true})
}
```

Is it possible to create a webm livestream from the capturestream? Or Do I need to shift to a an Image format?

Comment: You know how to do it with a gUM stream ? Should be the same. Also, call captureStream only once, after the canvas context has been initiated instead of calling it in a loop.

Comment: gUM stream? No i don't have idea on that. What is that?

Comment: getUserMedia API.

Comment: but how can I send it to websocket at least every second?

Comment: All this is called webRTC easy to find on your fevorite websearch service, impossible to go through in an answer.